# Can multiple aligned attributes in gcc be used to guarantee cache line separation?

Tags: c++, c, caching, gcc

I am trying to understand exactly how the aligned attribute in gcc works, and how it can be used to create cache-line-aligned data structures.  I have a struct with 2 members, which I want on different cache lines where a cache line is 64 Bytes.  I assume the following is *not* good enough because it will only guarantee the alignment of a single member:

```
struct alignTo64ByteCacheLine_BAD {
   int _onCacheLine1
   int _onCacheLine2 __attribute__((aligned(64)))
}
```

However are both of the following structs guaranteed to put their members on different cache lines?  Also, will the aligned(64) attribute on the struct itself pad the struct out to a multiple of 64-bytes for use in arrays, or does that have to be done manually?

```
struct alignTo64ByteCacheLine1 {
   int _onCacheLine1
   int _onCacheLine2 __attribute__((aligned(64)))
} __attribute__((aligned(64)))

struct alignTo64ByteCacheLine2 {
   int _onCacheLine1 __attribute__((aligned(64)))
   int _onCacheLine2 __attribute__((aligned(64)))
}
```

Comment: Try and tag just one of C or C++.

Comment: @tadman Perhaps he will accept answers in both? One of the rare times this combination might be fine.

Comment: @Mikhail Yeah, since this is a compiler question it's sort of on the fence, but speaking to the specific behaviour in one language is usually best.

Comment: C++ has special keyword for alignment, instead of gcc specific shown, so answers may differ.

Comment: C11 has a standard alignment specifier, too: `_Alignas`.  It also has a standard header that defines `alignas` as a macro that expands to `_Alignas`.  Thus, this GNU C extension is no longer needed, at least in recent enough GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a struct with 2 members, which I want on different cache lines
>   where a cache line is 64 Bytes. I assume the following is not good
>   enough because it will only guarantee the alignment of a single
>   member:
>
> ```
> struct alignTo64ByteCacheLine_BAD {
>    int _onCacheLine1
>    int _onCacheLine2 __attribute__((aligned(64)))
> }
> ```

You are mistaken: the above code will result in *both* members being aligned on 64-bit addresses.  This follows from the facts that

- A structure's alignment requirement has to be a multiple of the alignment requirement of each member (else at least one member's alignment cannot be guaranteed), and
- There cannot be padding before the first member.

With the struct having only two members, therefore, specifying an alignment for the second ensures that the first will have at least as strict an alignment.  Thus, this alternative has the same practical effect as each of your other two.

Moreover, that ensures that each member is at the *beginning* of its cache line, which is a stronger requirement than you expressed.  If you indeed need only that the members be on different cache lines then aligning only the second would be sufficient anyway, because the first member has to be laid out ahead of the second in memory.

Note also, however, that this appears extremely inefficient.  The alignment requirements will require the compiler to pad this structure to an overall size of (at least) 128 bytes, of which only 8 are used (since we're talking about GCC, we know we have 4-byte `int`s).  Each member will be the only thing in its cache line.  You didn't say why you want this, but it seems likely to impact your cache hit rate pretty hard.

> Also, will the aligned(64) attribute on the struct itself pad the
>   struct out to a multiple of 64-bytes for use in arrays, or does that
>   have to be done manually?

The struct size will be padded to a multiple of its alignment requirement, exactly so that arrays of the type do not force any elements to be misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged C++, I'll say that

- C++11 offers a way to specify alignment, namely `alignas`:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas

> The alignas specifier may be applied to the declaration of a variable
>   or a non-bitfield class data member, or it can be applied to the
>   declaration or definition of a class/struct/union or enumeration.

Here are some examples from the link above:

```
// every object of type sse_t will be aligned to 16-byte boundary
struct alignas(16) sse_t
{
  float sse_data[4];
};

// the array "cacheline" will be aligned to 128-byte boundary
alignas(128) char cacheline[128];
```

- C++17 defines [`std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) as the minimum offset between two objects to avoid false sharing (hence, the size of a cacheline). So `alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size)` will work in a portable way.

Comment: When next years cpu requires a 256 byte alignment, will my binary re-arrange its data structures?   This doesn’t even work across a cpu family, never mind being portable.

Comment: @mevets no, binaries don't do that.